# Open a Twitter tweet by native Twitter app on android

Tags: android, twitter

A tweet can be opened by Browser with the link of format:

> http://twitter.com/1Direction_X/statuses/197752514391715842

How do I open the above tweet by the native Twitter app from my app.

With iOS, I can do by this statement:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitter://status?id=197752514391715842"]];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

On Android, you can use this link to open the tweet in the native Twitter app

twitter://status?status_id=197752514391715842

Comment: could you please elaborate more

Comment: If you wanted to view a particular tweet in a browser, you would use an intent like this:  `Intent tweet_in_browser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://twitter.com/<screen_name>/status/<tweet_id>"));`  If you wanted to view a particular tweet in the Twitter native app, you would use an intent like this:  `Intent tweet_in_native_app = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("twitter://status?status_id=<tweet_id>"));`  I use the twitter4j library to query for tweets and then use the getId() function on the tweet to get the <tweet_id>.

Comment: Is there any way to open twitter app directly as a  tweet reply or retweet in the same way as: twitter://status?status_id=?

Answer (score 2):

You normally use the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` intent to open up the share dialog, where users can then select the twitter app.

I've found this tutorial that can be used to launch the twitter app directly: 
http://blog.rafaelsanches.com/2010/06/18/using-native-twitter-app-intent-to-share-on-android/

Comment: Link is dead. (Not surprising after 4½ years.)

+1 for mentioning the share dialog, though.